# Cancel Button is not working AlertDialod Android

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, cancel-button

In my App I have created an Alertdialog with a Title, listview item and Cancel button. I have set Item click on each of the item of the list. So if user click on item, it will generate another Alertdialog with a title, listview and cancel. The cancel button for first Alerdialog is working properly. But the cancel button of the second Alerdialog is nnot working. I am no finding out what would be the reason behind it. I have implemented the similar code. Here is my code.

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

private ListView listView1;
private ListView listView2;
private Button cancelButton1;
private Button cancelButton2;
private String[] companyName;
private String[] actionName;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

public AlertDialogFragment(){
        // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setCancelable(true);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_alertlist_contact, container, false);

        //Set Title Dialog
        getDialog().setTitle("Contact");

        //Button,ListView1 Initialization
        listView1=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        cancelButton1=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button1);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        companyName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.company_name);

        //Create and set Adepter TO ListView1
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.first_alertlist_textstyle,android.R.id.text1,companyName);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

        cancelButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

       listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // ListView Clicked item index
                int itemPosition = position;

                if(itemPosition == 0)
                {
                    dismiss();
                    showDialog2();
                }

                if(itemPosition == 1)
                {
                    dismiss();
                    showDialog2();
                }
                if(itemPosition == 2)
                {
                    ....
                }
            }

        });
        return rootView;
    }

    private void showDialog2(){

        final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity(), R.style.DialogStyle);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_alertlist_contact, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        listView2 = (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        cancelButton2=(Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button2);


        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        actionName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.contact_way);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
                R.layout.first_alertlist_textstyle, android.R.id.text1, actionName);

        listView2.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // ListView Clicked item index
                int itemPosition = position;

                if(itemPosition == 0)
                {
                    dismiss();
                    System.out.println("Hello");;
                }

               ...

            }

        });
        cancelButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialogBuilder.show();


    }
```

}

Here is my XML code for first AlertDialog

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Contact"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#283593"/>

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#283593"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

And XML code for Second Alert

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="What do you want to do"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#283593"/>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#283593"/>
```

Comment: Try to use dialogBuilder.cancel() or dialogBuilder.dismiss()

Comment: @yash786 it is showed cannot resolve methos

Comment: Ktina, Try to use below code i had just make a custom dialog for you.
Try to reuse 1 dialog for 2 purpose.

Comment: alertDilaouge.dismiss(); you should use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to post this as an answer and not a comment because of my reputation. However, does the AlertDialog contain the list view?
So in your AlertDialog, you will have 

Title

LISTVIEW

Cancel

I will then edit this post a solution if that is the case. Your code is very quirky... so I think the best bet is to start from scratch.

EDITED WITH CODE BELOW

```
//Create a new builder and get the layout.
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
View builderView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_listview, null);

//Set the layout inside of the builder
builder.setView(builderView);

//Show the dislog
final AlertDialog alert = builder.show();

//Get the TextView, ListView, Button from the layout.
TextView alertTitle = (TextView) builderView.findViewById(R.id.alertTitle);
Button alertButton = (Button) builderView.findViewById(R.id.alertButton);
ListView alertListView = (ListView) builderView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

alertTitle.setText("YOU CAN SET THIS TO WHATEVER");

//Click the alert button from within the alert will dismiss the dialog box
alertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        alert.dismiss();
    }
});
```

alert_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:id="@+id/alertTitle"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/alertTitle">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:id="@+id/alertButton"
            android:text="BUTTON"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

HERE IT IS WITH A LIST INSIDE THE DIALOG

```
//Create a new builder and get the layout.
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
View builderView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_listview, null);

//Set the layout inside of the builder
builder.setView(builderView);

//Show the dislog
final AlertDialog alert = builder.show();

List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("1");
arrayList.add("2");
arrayList.add("3");
arrayList.add("4");
arrayList.add("5");
arrayList.add("6");
arrayList.add("7");
arrayList.add("8");
arrayList.add("9");
arrayList.add("10");
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, arrayList);

//Get the TextView, ListView, Button from the layout.
TextView alertTitle = (TextView) builderView.findViewById(R.id.alertTitle);
Button alertButton = (Button) builderView.findViewById(R.id.alertButton);
ListView alertListView = (ListView) builderView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

alertListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

alertTitle.setText("YOU CAN SET THIS TO WHATEVER");

//Click the alert button from within the alert will dismiss the dialog box
alertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        alert.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Dridev Yes in each alerdialog I will have Title, Listview and dialog

Comment: @ktina will the listviews contain different information?

Comment: ok, i added the code above. this will display the dialog. inside of the dialog (xml included) . you will see the cancel button. from there....inside of the code, you can dismiss that way. ive tested this also, it works.

Comment: you may need to add onclick listeners to your add if you want to display certain information. However, you DO NOT have to make another xml file. You can use the same one and just push in different data into the list view.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**Just Implement the below code **/

companyName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.company_name);

selectData(companyName);

private void selectData(final ArrayList<String> array_data)
{
    final Dialog dialog_data = new Dialog(context);

    dialog_data.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    dialog_data.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    dialog_data.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alertdialog);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp_number_picker = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    Window window = dialog_data.getWindow();
    lp_number_picker.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());

    lp_number_picker.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp_number_picker.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    window.setAttributes(lp_number_picker);



    TextView alertdialog_textview = (TextView) dialog_data.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_textview);
    alertdialog_textview.setText("Contact");
    alertdialog_textview.setHint("Contact");

    Button dialog_cancel_btn = (Button) dialog_data.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel_btn);
    dialog_cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(dialog_data != null)
            {
                dialog_data.dismiss();
                dialog_data.cancel();
            }

        }
    });

    EditText filterText = (EditText) dialog_data.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_edittext);
    ListView alertdialog_Listview = (ListView) dialog_data.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_Listview);
    alertdialog_Listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    final ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, array_data);
    alertdialog_Listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    alertdialog_Listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            actionName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.contact_way);

            int itemPosition = position;

            if(itemPosition == 0)
            {
                selectData(actionName);
            }

            if(itemPosition == 1)
            {
                selectData(actionName);
            }
            if(itemPosition == 2)
            {
                ....
            }



            if(dialog_data != null)
            {
                dialog_data.dismiss();
                dialog_data.cancel();
            }
        }
    });

    filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    });

    dialog_data.show();
}

/*** custom_alertdialog.xml ***/

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/alertdialog_linearlayout"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:background="@null">

  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
  android:background="@color/white">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/alertdialog_textview"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/select_state"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16sp"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dimen_10dp"/>

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/alertdialog_edittext"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:textStyle="normal"
      android:textColorHint="@color/edittext_hint_color"
      android:textColor="@color/edit_profile_text_color"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
      android:gravity="start"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:theme="@style/alertdialog_edittextTheme"
      android:layout_gravity="start" />

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/alertdialog_Listview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
      android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

  </LinearLayout>

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/dialog_cancel_btn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_30dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="@string/X"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>

   </RelativeLayout>


    /**round_button**/

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="oval"
android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
android:useLevel="false" >

<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

<size android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"/>

<stroke android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/black"/>
```

Comment: your code is not clear to me. I have to change my entire code for this. Also I do not need round button